# How do you debug a Node.js server running with Chrome/WebKit as the remote debugger?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, webkit

If you have your Node running

```
node --debug server.js
```

This gives me a port number xxxx, should I use this port number when starting Chrome?

Do you remote debug into it from `Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=xxxx`?

Or is the 9222 a magic port, as it is mentioned all over.

Am I on the right track, trying to start Chrome with `--remote-debugger` into the Node.js `server.js`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The node-inspector / --debug are now replaced by inspector
See update below**

```
#now deprecated / see below for update

#install node-inspector
npm install -g node-inspector

#start node-inspector, listen on port 8080 (default)
node-inspector --web-port=8080

#in another terminal session/window:
#while node-inspector is running, start your project in debug mode 
node --debug myproject.js
```

Now you can browse to http://your_server:8080 for a full debug session of myproject.js

If your remote server is not accessible on the remote port because of firewalls or other reasons, you could create an ssh-tunnel to it from port 8080 on your local machine to 'localhost:8080' on the remote server:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 username@remoteserver -N
```

and keep this running while you use http://localhost:8080 on your local machine to debug your remote nodejs session

---

**Update august 2017**

Start node in inspect mode:

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 myproject.js
```

or if you want the debugger to break at the first line of myproject.js:

```
node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 myproject.js
```

Then open the following URL in your chrome browser:

```
chrome://inspect
```

Click the 'Configure...' button and add the following target:

```
ip-or-name-of-server-running-node:9229
```

After you click the 'Done' button, you should see myproject.js under your remote targets. Click the inspect link to start debugging. Unfortunately, the inspect link does not work on Chrome 58 for Ubuntu. It works fine on Chrome 60 for Windows.

Comment: Do you know if i have to start node-inspector explicitly like in your example when running a meteor server?

Comment: Thanks! Works fine for me with `chrome://inspect/`, however fails with VS Code (Attached but breakpoints do not work) and IntelliJ IDEA (Prints "Connecting to ip...") and nothing else happen.

Comment: for inspect with forever and reload when you save it use this
`forever -w -c 'node --inspect=127.0.0.1:3333' file.js`

Answer (score 9):

Use [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) to remotely debug your node application from Chrome that you've started with the `--debug` option as you've shown.

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of Node (> v6.3.0) and Chrome now allow you to use the Chrome Developer Tools to [debug a Node.JS process](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js) without having to install anything else.  Just pass `--inspect` to `node`:

```
$ node --inspect script.js

Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://SOME-URL-HERE
```

Just open that URL in Chrome, and you're good to go.

If you need to pause your script immediately after Node starts, you can also pass `--debug-brk` in the same command.

Answer (score 0):

- using
  $ vagrant ssh -- -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858

  ```
    to ssh connect to VM. also this comment would start a proxy server on port 5858;
  ```
- you could test using telnet 127.0.0.1 5858 to see if local proxy server started or not.
- In VM, you can start node with command
- $ node --debug-brk app.js
- set up debug configuration in web storm.
- when you start debug in web storm, node.js server in VM will start in a few seconds.

PS: there is no need to touch the vagrant file.
Reference: [Connecting WebStorm to a remote node.js debugging session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633924/connecting-webstorm-to-a-remote-node-js-debugging-session).