# How to connect to a remote nodejs debug session using PhpStorm / WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, webstorm, remote-debugging

There appears to be a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633924/connecting-webstorm-to-a-remote-node-js-debugging-session) as it about the predecessor to `inspect`, and I want to use `inspect`.

I have created a basic docker-compose stack from which I run my nodejs application. I want to listen for the debugger session and debug my JavaScript code within my local WebStorm.

I enter the container via

```
docker exec -it my_container bash
```

And I call my nodejs script with the debugger running via `inspect`:

```
node --inspect ./cli.js start mytask
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/81006264-163c-40d7-bd75-64c5e4fca618
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

The linked help is not helpful to me as it assumes that I want to use the `inspect` for a local run:

> JetBrains WebStorm 2017.1+ and other JetBrains IDEs Create a new
>   Node.js debug configuration and hit Debug. --inspect will be used by
>   default for Node.js 7+. To disable uncheck
>   js.debugger.node.use.inspect in the IDE Registry.

I want to attach to the run inside the docker container from my host WebStorm.

So when I run the script, it just completes never hitting any breakpoint.

I suppose I have to listen to the debugger, yet I do not know how.

I want my local WebStorm to connect to the nodejs debugger. I want to be able to debug within WebStorm as if I have run the nodejs script through WebStorm itself.

I tried digging through the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#ws_node_debug_remote_environment) yet I am unsure how to follow the guidelines.

I have exposed the default debug port `9229` to my local machine in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    my_container:
        build: .
        command: "bash"
        hostname: my_container
        tty: true
        environment:
            TERM: xterm
        ports:
            - "9229:9229"
```

I have no idea on how to listen to the nodejs debugger in WebStorm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to start your app with `node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229` (`0.0.0.0` is required as Node.js only binds to localhost by default) and then use [Attach to Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) Run configuration to attach the debugger. **Port** should be set to `9229`

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround as I very much still want to use WebStorm's debugger, which is why this is not a solution for me but at least provides a way to debug:

For chrome's dev tools, you can use:

```
node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 ./cli.js start mytask
```

It will show at:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

You can click inspect and debug through the script.

`--inspect-brk` will break on first line, and I have to use the ip `0.0.0.0` for the dev-tools to pick it up.