# Remote debugging NodeJS in Docker with Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, debugging, docker, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use the official `node` docker image for my app. However I cannot get the remote debugger to work on the host machine. I am using Visual Studio Code to connect to the remote debugger.

The strange thing is using an unofficial image `cusspvz/node` the remote debugger works correctly.

When I run `docker log` against the `cusspvz/node` instance of the container I get the following output:

`Debugger listening on [::]:5858`

However when I run `docker log` against the `node` instance of the container I get:

`Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858`

Which leads me to believe that the debugger is listening on the wrong IP address (should be wildcard rather than localhost?)

I've tried the built in debugger as well as the nodemon. Unfortunately I couldn't get node-inspector to work as it fails to install (appears that the build is failing anyway).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /scraper
EXPOSE 5858
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "if [ -z \"$REMOTE_DEBUGGING\" ]; then node --debug index.js; else node --debug-brk index.js; fi"]
COPY . /scraper
RUN npm install
```

I'm starting the container with docker-compose, using this YML file:

```
version: '2'

services:
 alt.nphotos.imagescraper:
  container_name: nscraper
  hostname: nscraper
  build:
   context: ./ALT.NPhotos.ImageScraper
   dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug
  environment:
  - REMOTE_DEBUGGING=1
  - AMQP_CONNECTIONSTRING=amqp://guest:guest@nqueue
  ports:
  - "5858:5858"
```

Any ideas? - TIA!

Comment: complete side note to you question: you should specify a version number tag with your `FROM` instruction. `FROM node:6.9.5` for example... otherwise, every time you build your image, you'll end up with the latest / newest node version. that sounds good at first, until an unwanted upgrade breaks your code

Comment: Thanks @DerickBailey I'll bear that in mind

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440169/how-do-you-debug-a-node-js-server-running-with-chrome-webkit-as-the-remote-debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default node.js (and v8 behind it) always use 127.0.0.1 for the debugger. I've looked at `cusspvz/node` and I can't find anywhere how it exposes the debugger like that.

It used to be difficult to change this configuration but now you can just use the debug option with an explicit host:

```
node --debug=[::]:5858 test.js
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! I did actually try something very similar - with debug-brk and I couldn't get it working which is why I assumed this method wouldn't work either. This is what I saw, any ideas?

`Debugger listening on [::]:5858

module.js:563
      Debug.setBreakPoint(compiledWrapper, 0, 0);
            ^
illegal access`


However, as you've saved me - I will award the bounty :) Thanks very much.

Comment: @AdrianLucaThomas, I have the same error for debug-brk. Even when using `0.0.0.0` instead of `[::]`. If it's important for you, you can still use `socat` to redirect port. It is a workaround I used previously.

Comment: @AdrianLucaThomas, does it work for you if you combine both? `node --debug=[::]:5858 --debug-brk test.js` ? I am able to break on first line this way.

Comment: Yes! That worked :-) thank you ever so much. I've had a lot of pain with this one..